# Scala understanding signatures

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In Scala (Play Framework), I can't understand the type signatures even though I read through all the symbols in [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-symbols.html).

For example:

```
/* matches if a == b */
def equalTo[T](t: => T): BeEqualTo

class BeEqualTo(t: => Any)
extends BeTypedEqualTo[Any]
```

What on earth do these type signatures even mean?

For example, what exactly is "a" and "b" in the documentation? All I see is "t". Is equalTo a function that takes in a function which returns a value of generic type T?

Another example...

Say I have this line...

```
status(home).must(equalTo(OK))
```

According to the IDE, OK is a pattern or symbol of type Int. So OK is an Int? You can monkey-patch an int to give it a function like "must", but how can an Int go inside of "equalTo", a function that takes in a function?

Now some of the type signatures make sense. For example...

```
def status(of: Future[Result])(implicit timeout: Timeout): Int
```

^ This is a curried function that takes in a future that returns something of type Result and that sucks in an implicit parameter of type Timeout from somewhere (Scala magic) and returns an Int. "home" is of type "Future[Result]", so it fits inside "status".

But other stuff...

```
contentType(home).must(beSome.which(_ == "text/html"))
```

^ My IDE says that beSome is of type

```
def beSome[T](check: ValueCheck[T]): SomeCheckedMatcher[T]
```

^ So "beSome" is a function. If that is the case, then how on earth can I appeand ".which()", another function, to it as if it were an object?

Another example...

```
def which[R : AsResult](f: (U) => R): OptionLikeCheckedMatcher[F, Nothing, U]
```

^ How on earth do you read these type signatures? "which" takes in "f: (U)", or a variable which we call "f" of type "(U)"? Why the unnecessary parenthesis around the "(U)"? Can't you just say "f: U" and make U be a String if R is a String?

"must" is like this...

```
def must(m: => Matcher[T]): MatchResult[T]
```

^ So "must" takes in a function that returns a Matcher. But "which" is passing in an OptionLikeCheckedMatcher. "m: => Matcher[T]" is a function that takes in an "m" and returns a "Matcher[T]". How is that the same as an object of type OptionLikeCheckedMatcher?

Can someone provide a definitive guide as to how to read Scala type signatures?

Comment: Your question is too long to make a complete answer, however, one   thing I can tell you is "not to trust IDE too much", especially when you are writing Scala. For `beSome`, there is two declarations which takes one argment and no argment. http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/api/SPECS2-2.3.12/index.html#org.specs2.matcher.OptionMatchers

Comment: So _ == "text/html" is an function with a generic parameter "_". This function is being passed into "which", which is a field inside of SomeMatcher[T], the return type after calling the no argument "beSome" function. The which function takes this anonymous function in {} and returns an OptionLikeCheckedMatcher[Option, String, String] or OptionLikeCheckedMatcher[F, Nothing, String] (I can't really tell), but the "_" in the anonymous function is a String.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're getting a little confused with the distinction between a function-valued parameter and a call-by-name parameter. They are similar but not quite the same. In the first example you posted, `def equalTo[T](t: => T): BeEqualTo`, the : => notation means that the parameter is not evaluated immediately (as it would be if it were declared with just a colon), but every time it is used in an expression. This link might clarify things a bit for you: https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/06/26/call-by-name.html

In another example you posted, `def which[R: AsResult](f: (U) => R): OptionCheckedLikeMatcher[F, Nothing, U]` takes in a function parameter called f, which accepts a U as its argument and returns a T. The brackets around the U are indeed unnecessary, but they would have been necessary if (for example) f were a function taking 2 parameters of type U - we would then have written it as `f: (U, U) => R`. The return value of `which` will be an OptionCheckedMatcher. Assuming that this is a subtype of Matcher (which seems sensible), this is the value which is passed to `must`.

Comment: Oh, I see. "whenTrue: => Type" means "whenTrue: (=> Type)" not "whenTrue: (_ => Type)".

Comment: Generic parameter R is of type "AsResult". Why do they call the generic parameter "R" and not "T" in this scenario? Are "U" and "F" actual names of classes in Scala? I've seen abstract types before, but only inside class bodies, never in type signatures.

Comment: I suspect he meant "accepts a U as its argument and returns an R".

Comment: Where "U" in this case is "String" and "R" is "Boolean"

Comment: Whoops, yes, well spotted @emote_control. And no, U and F aren't names of any classes (that I know of - please don't write any ;) ) - I guess they just run out of generic parameter variables after a while?

Comment: In the example, yes.  But the fact that it uses "_" as the input parameter in the anonymous function indicates that it can take any type for U.  However, since it's comparing it to a String, the only thing that will return 'true' is a String.  But for the purpose of matchers, it's flexible enough to tell you that no, your Int is not equal to this String.  Which can sometimes be helpful.